# Finding AVG of Rows and merging in to one in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following screenshot, you can see city rows repeating 3 time ang with different values so I need to merge 3 cities into one ang, its value should be its average value.

[image]

Thanks 
sai kumar

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to them.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
SELECT [Metric_Name]
      ,AVG(THSLD_RANGE_TO_VAL)
FROM [mytable]
GROUP BY [Metric_Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query

```
SELECT Metric_Name,AVG(THSLD_RANGE_TO_VAL) as Average
FROM MetricTable
WHERE Metric_Name='CITY'
GROUP BY Metric_Name
```